# Apache Avro is not generating UUID

Tags: java, avro, avro-tools

Avro is not generating UUID class in code for fields no mater what I tried.

Versions: 1.8.2 & 1.9.1

I tried to generate UUID with such schema:

```
  "type": "record",
  "name": "RecordWithUUID",
  "namespace": "avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "uuid",
      "type": {
        "type": "string",
        "logicalType": "uuid"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the class from Avro project test class `TestReflectLogicalTypes`::`RecordWithUUID`
So, in short this is example of schema that Avro uses to test their code functionality and I expected that it should work.

I run like this to get java code from my scheme:

`java -jar avro-tools-1.8.2.jar compile schema my_scheme.avsc .`

`java -jar avro-tools-1.9.1.jar compile schema my_scheme.avsc .`

The **initial class code from Avro** is like this:

```
class RecordWithUUID {
  UUID uuid; // <- UUID (!!!)

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return uuid.hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
      return false;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof RecordWithUUID)) {
      return false;
    }
    RecordWithUUID that = (RecordWithUUID) obj;
    return this.uuid.equals(that.uuid);
  }
}
```

Here is code that I got after generating:

**1.8.2 avro-tools from command line**

```
  ..

@SuppressWarnings("all")
@org.apache.avro.specific.AvroGenerated
public class RecordWithUUID extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase implements org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 9147582668665082277L;
  public static final org.apache.avro.Schema SCHEMA$ = new org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser().parse("{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"RecordWithUUID\",\"namespace\":\"avro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"uuid\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"logicalType\":\"uuid\"}}]}");
  public static org.apache.avro.Schema getClassSchema() { return SCHEMA$; }

  ..

  @Deprecated public java.lang.CharSequence uuid; //<- NO UUID

  ..
```

**1.9.1 avro-tools from command line**

```
 ..

@org.apache.avro.specific.AvroGenerated
public class RecordWithUUID extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase implements org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 9147582668665082277L;
  public static final org.apache.avro.Schema SCHEMA$ = new org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser().parse("{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"RecordWithUUID\",\"namespace\":\"avro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"uuid\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"logicalType\":\"uuid\"}}]}");
  public static org.apache.avro.Schema getClassSchema() { return SCHEMA$; }

  ..

   private java.lang.CharSequence uuid; //<- NO UUID
  ..
```

**maven plugin for avro 1.8.2/1.9.1**

```
  ..

@org.apache.avro.specific.AvroGenerated
public class RecordWithUUID extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase implements org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 9147582668665082277L;
  public static final org.apache.avro.Schema SCHEMA$ = new org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser().parse("{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"RecordWithUUID\",\"namespace\":\"avro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"uuid\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\",\"logicalType\":\"uuid\"}}]}");
  public static org.apache.avro.Schema getClassSchema() { return SCHEMA$; }

  ..

   private java.lang.String uuid;//<- NO UUID
  ..
```

So, is it a bug or I'm doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Try 1.10.0-SNAPSHOT, I have it working there (after experiencing the same issues as you with the other versions)

Comment: Same in 1.10.2. Perhaps the OP and others are missing something.

Comment: apparantly maven PR is still pending see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2621

Comment: @bestwishes - i simply used a newer version, there was nothing to resolve as such. Let me see if i can post a test somewhere

Comment: are you using gradle? if possible can you please post the snippet as an answer? it will certainly help lots of folks.